# Difference in farm with form library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services, forms-library

I have 2 SharePoint 2013 farms. On both I have a web application with a site collection containing a Form library. On farm 1, when I open the item callout menu with ... I see this

[image]

The entire path of my form is shown. On my other farm I see

[image]

I see something with FormServer.aspx. Why do I see this difference?
I tried playing with the open in client or browser setting and client integration settings bu no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found why I see the difference in url's

On my second farm I have InfoPath designer installed for development purposes. When InfoPath is installed, and you open the site in IE, it checks if InfoPath is installed. When installed you get screenshot 1 (with xml path) and it is opened in InfoPath. When InfoPath is not installed it automatically assumes you use InfoPath form server and you see the formserver.aspx page url. This also works together with the library setting open in client or browser. In Chrome you always get the formserver.aspx because the detection if InfoPath is installed only works in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my environment, the entire path of my form is shown in the callout menu of form library.

Try to create a new form library in the farm which shows FormServer.aspx, compare whether all form libraries just show FormServer.aspx.

Comment: What type of sitecollection have you tested this in? Did you activate any extra features?

Comment: Team site, i have activated "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" site collection feature and "SharePoint Server Publishing" feature.

Comment: Hi Lisa, thx for the help. I figured it out. It was because InfoPath was installed on my second farm.